# Can't get requestId from Facebook ios app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Sending an invitation request with a FBDialog and "apprequests" param, I can't get the requestid when users click on the app on the bookmark list but only when they click on the notification itself.